# How to route traffic to a subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have a personal website hosted on AWS using S3, Route53, and CloudFront: [index.luoweilue.com](https://index.luoweilue.com), `route53 (index.luoweilue.com) -> cloudfront -> s3`, I want to redirect all users from `luoweilue.com` to `index.luoweilue.com`, so I created 2 records in Route53 in the `luoweilue.com` hosted zone, and I thought it would look like: `route53 (luoweilue.com) -> route53 (index.luoweilue.com) -> cloudfront -> s3`:

[image: records]

but when I try to access `luoweilue.com`, it says:
[image: error]

May I know what did I do wrong here? Do I need to do anything else to redirect traffic?

##### Update 1:

I think I do have certificates for both domains:
[image: cert]

##### Update 2:

DNS lookup shows that they resolve to the same address:
[image: dnslookup]

Comment: You have ssl cert for `index.luoweilue.com`. Did you also register it for `luoweilue.com`?

Comment: @Marcin Hi, I believe I have SSL cert for both of the domains, updated in the question description.

Comment: First , can you check if domains are resolving as expected using nslookup or dig ? both should resolve to same address or IP's .

Comment: @SuryaPrakashPatel Hi, they do show the same values for addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments (@Marcin, @SuryaPrakashPatel), turns out I also need to add `luoweilue.com` to the alternate domain name in the CloudFront distribution:

[image: cloudfront]